# Making calls via internet in android

Tags: android, sip, webrtc, voip

What are the available API or existing technologies on android that can help one make call using the internet, more like VOIP. I checked out documentation online including [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/sip.html)
. Kinda confused where to start. Can anyone help with a better guideline ? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

PJSIP is one of the better media libraries available on Android. you may want to google the pro and cons of this vs the native android SIP Api and based on your project pick one over the other.

There are a few others, but PJSIP is one comprehensive solution.

Answer (score 1):

There are plenty of support for VOIP on android. You can try the following options

1. For Android 2.3 or higher you can use inbuilt SIP stack [Documentation here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/sip.html)
2. [PJSIP](http://www.pjsip.org/) (example implementation Project for Android is [CSIPsimple](https://code.google.com/p/csipsimple/))
3. [MJSIP](http://mjsip.org/mjua.html) (example implementation Project for Android is [Sip Droid](http://sipdroid.org/))
4. [Doubango](http://www.doubango.org/) (example implementation Project for Android is [IMSDroid](https://code.google.com/p/imsdroid/))
5. [Linphone](http://www.linphone.org/technical-corner/linphone/overview)

I have used almost all of the above and they all are good and do the intended.

There are plenty of Paid SDK in market too which promise to do the job for you.