# Is adding a libjitsi dependency to an Android project feasible?

Tags: android, voip, rtp

I am actually working on an Android VOIP application that let user create conference with other users. My constraints are to avoid any use of a server like SIP servers to realise it and if I have to use a external library, it should be under LGPL license. I have succesfully done it in a peer-to-peer fashion using the [AudioGroup](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/rtp/AudioGroup.html) and [AudioStream](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/rtp/AudioStream.html) classes of the android RTP stack.

My problem occurs in a 3-peers conference. Using AudioGroup, I have enabled the `MODE_ECHO_SUPPRESSION` but the results are very poor and I can hear my echo after 3 seconds. I came to conclusion that the Android RTP stack was not a good solution to my problem beacause using AudioGroup make impossible to tweek the sound and echo suppression seems to function badly.

By testing VOIP applications, I discovered a lot that were working pretty weel and more precisely Jitsi ([homepage](https://jitsi.org/Main/HomePage)) which use a java library based on native code for the RTP stuff under the LGPL licence. I tried to follow [this tutorial](http://blog.sharedmemory.fr/en/2014/07/07/gsoc-2014-libjitsi-tutorial/) to use libjitsi but unfortunatly it gives me an error... At this time, I'm not sure that it is possible to use Libjitsi on an android project as it is normally used in Java projects.

### Steps I went trough to get the error (using Android Studio)

- I have compiled libjitsi from the build.xml contained in the [sources](https://github.com/jitsi/libjitsi) and putted the resulting jar  directly in the lib/ folder of my project.
- I have added a dependency to libjitsi.jar in my build.gradle file
- Called the static method `Libjitsi.start()` in the onCreate method of an activity

### Error log

> 01-02 17:06:48.304    1523-1523/com.test.example I/LibJitsi﹕
>   Failed to initialize LibJitsi backend
>   org.jitsi.impl.libjitsi.LibJitsiOSGiImpl. (Exception stack trace
>   follows.) Will try an alternative.
>       java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.osgi.framework.FrameworkUtil
>               at org.jitsi.impl.libjitsi.LibJitsiOSGiImpl.(LibJitsiOSGiImpl.java:34)
>               at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
>               at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1319)
>               at org.jitsi.service.libjitsi.LibJitsi.start(LibJitsi.java:227)
>               at org.jitsi.service.libjitsi.LibJitsi.start(LibJitsi.java:171)
>               at com.test.example.ui.createconf.CreateConfActivity.onCreate(CreateConfActivity.java:76)
>               at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
>               at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1931)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1992)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:127)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1158)
>               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4441)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
>               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
>               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
>               at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native

Now if anyone already tried to use libjitsi on an AndroidProject or if you know it's not feasible, I would really be gratefull if you share your experience with me.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Yes libjitsi dependency can be added to android, you can try [jitsi-android](https://github.com/jitsi/jitsi-android) which is an Android port of the [Jitsi](https://jitsi.org/) project . I have tried to run their sample app and it compiled fine.

However , I have shared 5 different libraries for VOIP calling on android [in another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26880819/2319390) you can have a look and try them.

Njoy!

Comment: Tank you for the answer but my problem is that libjitsi-android application has the source code of the dependency directly in the project and I need to have it in a jar file because it is asked to me. This is why I am starting to think it is not possible to use it as a jar dependency in my android project...

Comment: Hello @shubhang , can you please gave a look at this thread ...i am getting problem in running the jitsi android project in my eclipse ...here is the link of my problem :-
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32842371/conversion-to-dalvik-format-failed-with-error-1-while-compiling-jitsi-project

Comment: @sid, I am also facing the same issue. have you solved this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32842371/conversion-to-dalvik-format-failed-with-error-1-while-compiling-jitsi-project ? please  help me. Thanks!!