# Conversion to Dalvik format failed with error 1 while compiling jitsi project

Tags: java, android, eclipse, webrtc, jitsi

I am trying to compile and run the project
https://github.com/jitsi/jitsi-android on Eclipse by Importing.

I have imported the project successfully,Added External Jar files and Fix some of compilation errors.

When I try to run app, It is giving

Conversion to Dalvik format failed with error 1 Error on the console.So that I Clean the project, checked the all the jar files from Order and Export tab and build it again.

but it doesn't work for me.

Finally, I unchecked the all the libraries from Order and Export tab,build and run it again.

But still its giving me same error and my application is getting crashed every time i run it.

Any help will be appreciated , i really want to run this application.

here is my libs folder screenshot:-
[image]

Comment: Hello @sid, Have you found any solution? I am also facing the same issue. Please help me. Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same problem once.

**Here is what I found out when I was trying to solve my issue:**

- The error is caused when there are two Classes/Packages with the same name (For example when LibaryX has Class org.a.b.c.Sample and LibaryY has class org.a.b.c.Sample aswell)
- **Different approaches which worked for some people** (So if you have the error yourself, make sure to test following things out):

**A)** Two Libaries have the exactly same package/class-> Delete the class in one of the Libaries

**B)** One Jar is detected twice because it's for example in the project source folder and in the Java Build Path Libaries aswell

**C)** Updating Proguard often fixes it aswell (Put the new Proguard jars in [Android SDK folder]\tools\proguard\lib)

**D)** Cleaning the Project also helped many people (you already did that, so that won't be your solution)

When I had this issue myself it was caused because I did not follow the instructions of one of the libaries that I used. After following the libary instructions step by step, everything worked fine again.

Greetings
Felix